# software that combines graph and spreadsheet flexibilities

Tags: windows, graphs, spreadsheet

I'm at the beginning of a big project and I want to find a tool that works somehow like this (using a simple example):

Suppose that you have some signal sources (e.x. sensors) that produce a voltage signal that goes through a voltage normalizer (e.x. voltage amplifier). Then a ADC does the conversion of the normalized signal using the required number of bits (specified by the Requirements node-entity) and the produced bits are saved in a memory.

The system model using a dependency graph could be like this:
[image: simple graph]

In a more detailed model it is clear that the values of some attributes (e.x. the size of the memory) are dependent on some others. The "text" column refers to a pseudo-formula that could be used, like excel.

[image: detailed graph]

So I want to create a model that uses dependent values-attributes (like in a spreadsheet) in the nodes-entities but still has the form of a graph. I could use a database design tool but this misses the flexibility of the spreadsheet, plus each time I add a node-entity I should add trigger events for the dependent values to update.

When the system model will be complete I'll have the complete specifications of each component.